# Custom fields are not visible in custom report type

Tags: reporting, custom-field, fields, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I am not able to see all the custom fields of an object in custom report type which is recently created. I have opened the report type and tried to edit the layout but the custom fields are not visible in even lookup. Kindly help with this

Comment: When you say layout, are you saying about the report-type layout?

Comment: does the admin have FLS to these fields?

Comment: Yes, I am saying about report type layout. Admin have fls to the field.